# Override Plugin Impl

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

There are

**plugin**

```
class MyService {
    String getFrom(){ return 'Service from plugin'}
}
class MyBean {
    String getFrom(){ return 'Bean from plugin'} 
}
```

**APP**

```
class MyAppBean {
    String getFrom(){ return 'Bean from App'}
}
package myappwithmyplugin
class MyAppService {
    String getFrom(){ return 'Service from App'}
}
```

*resources.groovy*

```
beans = {
    myBean(MyAppBean){}
    myService(MyAppService){}
}
```

*controller*

```
class MyController {
    def myBean
    def myService

    def index() { 
        println myBean.getFrom()
        println myService.getFrom()
    }
}
```

**Why a result is:**

Bean from App

Service from plugin

Comment: Which version of Grails you are using?

Comment: checkout this link maybe your have this issue http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10091

Comment: @Alidad Thanks! Could you repeat your comment as an answer. By the way, it resolves by ** myPluginMyService(MyAppService)**  in resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 2.2, to support namespacing, Grails register the concatenation of the plugin bean name and the beans like services. To override the service introduced by the plugin you need to use the pluginNameServiceName.

source: 
jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10091